# Creating a heatmap on keras

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, heatmap

I am trying to make a script that recognises breast cancer in mammographies. I have made a small database of 12 images (6 with breast cancer and 6 six without) to test whether it works before loading a (much) larger database. The code I've written (see bellow) successfully does this but now I want to make a heatmap of each picture to see where the script recognises the breast cancer.

```
library(EBImage)
library(keras)

mypic<-list()
for(i in 1:12){mypic[[i]]<-readImage(paste('test',i,'.jpg',sep=''))}


#resize
for(i in 1:12){
  mypic[[i]]<-resize(mypic[[i]], 100,100)
  if (i%%10==0){print(i)}
}

#reshape
for(i in 1:12){
  mypic[[i]]<-array_reshape(mypic[[i]], c(100,100,3))
  if (i%%10==0){print(i)}
}

#rowbind
trainx<- NULL
for(i in 1:5){
  trainx<-rbind(trainx, mypic[[i]])
}
for(i in 7:11){
  trainx<-rbind(trainx, mypic[[i]])
}
str(trainx)

testx<-rbind(mypic[[6]], mypic[[12]])
str(testx)

trainy<- c(1, 
           1, 
           1, 
           1, 
           1, 
           0, 
           0, 
           0, 
           0, 
           0)
testy<-c(1,0)


#train

trainLabels<-to_categorical(trainy)
testLabels<-to_categorical(testy)


#one hot
model<-keras_model_sequential()

model %>%
  layer_dense(units = 256, activation = 'relu', input_shape = c(30000))%>%
  layer_dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu') %>%
  layer_dense(units = 2, activation = 'sigmoid')


#compile
model %>%
  compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
          optimizer_rmsprop(),
          metrics = c('accuracy'))

#fitmodel

history<- model %>%
  fit(trainx,
      trainLabels,
      epochs = 15,
      batch = 32,
      validation_split = 0.2)

summary(history)
# Evaluation & Prediction - train data
model %>% evaluate(trainx, trainLabels)
pred <- model %>% predict_classes(trainx)
table(Predicted = pred, Actual = trainy)
prob <- model %>% predict_proba(trainx)
cbind(prob, Prected = pred, Actual= trainy)
```

I would like to make images similar to the picture below:

[image: Text]
Not sure if worth mentioning, but I use Rstudio in anaconda enviornment and I installed tensowflow-gpu from Keras. I've tried to install the Keras-vis package according to the [link](https://rdrr.io/github/jkhseo/Keras-Vis/). However, I get the error

```
Error: (converted from warning) package 'reticulate' was built under R version 3.6.2
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'KerasVis'
* removing 'D:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/envs/gputest/Lib/R/library/KerasVis'
```

I've tried the different options of installation updates (ALL, CRAN only, none, digest and PS) combined with installation of previous versions. All tips are welcome. Thanks in advance

Comment: Reinstall `reticulate`. Then try installing `KerasVis` again.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sadly that does not seem to work. I've tries to use the example in https://github.com/rstudio/keras/issues/182 without succes. Apparently it is possible to make these heatmaps without KerasVis.